# Blender python : where is bpy module located in windows 10

Tags: python

i'm trying to import bpy module from outside blender. Either using python terminal (command prompt) or IDE like pycharm/atom etc. The bpy is not available outside blender app. So i'm looking a way to access it. I'm thinking maybe to add the location of bpy to $PYTHONPATH. But the problem is in windows 10, can't find this module in installation directory. it seems to be stored in somewhere else.

Does anyone know where is the bpy module located in windows 10 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `bpy` module is Blender itself. It's automatically available inside Blender because when it starts the Python interpreter it also registers itself as a Python module.

If you want to load `bpy` as a module outside of Blender, you'll have to recompile Blender yourself. The [Wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule) has instructions on this. Basically, it's like a normal build of Blender, except you set those CMake config variables:

```
WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL=OFF
WITH_PLAYER=OFF
WITH_PYTHON_MODULE=ON
```